# Send TAB to a child console (windows)

Tags: .net, console, tab-completion

I create a child console application with

```
_process = new Process();
_process.StartInfo.FileName = @"cmd.exe";
_process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
_process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
_process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
_process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

_proccess.Start();
```

Now I can go to c:\aaa

```
_process.StandardInput.Write("cd c:\\aaa\xD\xA");
```

But normally user can type c:\ + TAB + ENTER. How can I do the same? This does not work:

```
_process.StandardInput.Write("cd c:\\\0x9\xD\xA");
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a fundamental difference between the *standard input* of the child process, and the console that it is attached to.  A command interpreter in interactive mode is expecting to be talking *either* to a console *or* to a pipe/file as its standard input, and it changes its behaviour to match which one it finds.  For a pipe/file, it just makes a simple call the [`ReadFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa365467%28VS.85%29.aspx) function.  For a console, however, it receives input through [`ReadConsoleInput()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms684961%28VS.85%29.aspx), where non-alphanumeric keys are recognizable by their virtual key codes.

See the [`ReadCommand()`](http://doxygen.reactos.org./da/d2c/base_2shell_2cmd_2cmd_8h_ab56d2b86e2487d35eab0eae73ba5afcb.html#ab56d2b86e2487d35eab0eae73ba5afcb) function in the ReactOS `CMD` for an example.

If you write a byte with the value 9 down a pipe to the standard input of a process, that's what it will see from its call to `ReadFile()`.  But it won't treat it as a <kbd>Tab</kbd> keypress, because (for starters) it isn't one; it's just byte value 9 coming down a pipe.  Moreover, the command-line editing that a command interpreter does in interactive mode only occurs when the standard input is detected to be a console, not when it is a pipe or a file.  The command interpreter uses `ReadConsoleInput()`, which doesn't read buffers of bytes but reads sequences of [`INPUT_RECORDs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms683499%28VS.85%29.aspx); and thus you have to [`WriteConsoleInput()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms687403%28VS.85%29.aspx) to that console handle an appropriate `INPUT_RECORD` simulating the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key if you want the command interpreter to see a <kbd>Tab</kbd> keypress in its input stream.

Of course, since you've set `StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput` to `true`, under the covers .NET has connected the standard input of the command interpreter process to a pipe; and so the command interpreter is just calling `ReadFile()`, without doing any interactive command-line editing, as it would if its standard input had been a console.  Even if you could find and open a handle to the command interpreter process' console, and write a `INPUT_RECORD` for a <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to it, the command interpreter is reading a pipe for its standard input, and ignoring its console.

If you want a command interpreter to act just as it would if it were talking to a console, command line editing and all, you have to spawn the process *with its standard input as a console*, whose handle you have to (then) obtain so that you can simulate keypresses with `WriteConsoleInput()`.  That's fairly difficult within .NET.

Answer (score 1):

What about dipping into the Windows API?

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
//...
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
private const int WM_CHAR = 0x0102;
private const int VK_TAB = 0x9;
private const int VK_RETURN = 0xD;
//...
SendMessage(_process.Handle, WM_CHAR, new IntPtr(VK_TAB), new IntPtr(0));
SendMessage(_process.Handle, WM_CHAR, new IntPtr(VK_RETURN), new IntPtr(0));
```

However that doesn't allways work according to [Kevin Montrose's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220820/how-do-i-send-key-strokes-to-a-window-without-having-to-activate-it-using-windows/1230643#1230643).