# Accepting input while out of focus

Tags: windows, winapi, focus, unity-game-engine, joystick

I've never actual asked a question on Stack Overflow, though just about every programming question I've ever had I found an answer here. Sadly today is not one of those days.

I've spent all day Googling, browsing the win32 api, and trying all sorts of things, but I just can't find the damn answer I'm looking for.

Here's the situation: I've got a Unity project I've created, it uses input from a joystick, there are other components to this project outside of unity, but that's irrelevant, the base of my problem is this: How can I make an application continue to accept input while it's out of focus/Inactive.

I know for a fact that it can be done because Borderlands 2 can do it (I found that out yesterday when I first started trying to find an answer, which was aggravating because that proves there is a way, and I'm failing to find it).

At the very least if someone knows how to do this for mouse or keyboard, that would be helpful enough to allow me to figure out how to apply it to a joystick.

Some helpful details: I'm an avid and experienced programmer, and I've been coding in: C/C++, C#, Java, and a number of scripting languages for many years. It is what I do as a hobby, for my job, in my spare time, <s>while I'm asleep</s>...

Things I've done / tried:

- using `SetFocus` + `SetActive` from `user32` & passing `null` as the window
  losing focus
- adding the `WM_KILLFOCUS` to the ignore list of the other window I want to read input while in background
- using `sendmessage` to trick the other window into reading input
- overriding the `inputstream` of the application (but this was useless sense I couldn't figure out how to send joystick input over
  the stream, and also because It still didn't solve the problem sense
  if that other application was out of focus (i.e. I open notepad),
  input would stop.
- I also searched for a way to make a Unity standalone game/project/application accept input while in background, but that yielded nothing.

Comment: Oh one more thing: I really don't want to have to go and use some 3rd party application to accomplish this, that somewhat undermines my whole ordeal.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I send key strokes to a window without having to activate it using Windows API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220820/how-do-i-send-key-strokes-to-a-window-without-having-to-activate-it-using-window)  Although it might not be the answer you were hoping for :(

Comment: Nope :/... I looked at that previously, but as mentioned it is in fact possible in some way otherwise my example wouldn't exist...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there is a Unity-related solution, but you can use the [RawInput API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645536.aspx) to receive events directly from the Mouse/Joystick/HID hardware regardless of whether your app is in focus or not.

Comment: I did look into the RawInput API and tried to use it previously, and again just last night, I can't figure out how exactly to push the input to the Unity app and have it properly received. Using SendInput, I attempted to send whatever I received from the joystick to unity, but unity didn't react... Could it be that the service I created to pull the input and forward it was blocked by UIPI ? 

It's a new day so maybe I'll have better luck than I did yesterday.

Comment: If you are referring to an actual background service, then it runs on its own desktop session and cannot send window messages to other desktop sessions. But why are you trying t capture input in a separate service and not from in the app that needs the input?

Comment: Did you make sure to enable `Run In Background`?  Found at `Edit -> Project Settings -> Player`

Comment: @Jerdak Yup, I think I've figured it out though, I don't think I was properly sending the input to unity, I'm in the process of testing this right now.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The are multiple parts to the project that each require input from different origins, that's why I'm using a separate app that'll run in the background and push the input to the appropriate part.

Answer (score 0):

I really think the answer given by @RemyLebeau is the proper way of tracking the input. If however you're into hacking, you could use `GetForegroundWindow`, `GetWindowThreadProcessId`, `AttachThreadInput` to attach to the active UI thread. But then you'd need to 'pull' the state of input (e.g., with `GetKeyState`, `GetKeyboardState` or `GetKeyboardState`) and track the focus as it switches threads to do detach/attach to a new thread. You can **not** just wait (say, with `GetMessage`) for an input message posted to a different thread.

Comment: I looked into use attach thread input and stuff, but It's only useful for the keyboard/mouse input, and as you said, you'd have to track the foreground window, and would lose input if no window is active sense you can't attach to a system thread

Comment: [off-topic] why would you want to steal joystick input while your app is not an active app to the user?[/off-topic]

Comment: Because for example, if you have a setup where there's an external interface, you want to be able to control the app while focus is on the external interface.