# Sending a keypress to the active window that doesn't handle Windows message in C#

Tags: c#, handle, keystroke

When I am detecting a pixel with a given color, I want to send the Key "k".
The problem is that even though the window is active, wit the following code it sends me an exception : **SendKeys cannot run inside this application because the application is not handling Windows messages.  Either change the application to handle messages, or use the SendKeys.SendWait method.** The Sendwait method doesn't seem to press the key fast enough (but at least it gives no exception). I don't really care if the required solution is "dirty", it's a poc I'll use once

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string ligne;
        string previousligne = string.Empty;
        int compteur = 0;        
            while (true)
            {
                Color pixColor = Win32.GetPixelColor(System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X, System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y);
                ligne = pixColor.Name;                    
                if (previousligne != ligne)
                {
                    if (ligne == "ffcecefe")
                    {
                        SendKeys.Send("k");
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine(ligne);
                    System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Users\Public\WriteLines.txt", "-----" + DateTime.Now.Minute + ":" + DateTime.Now.Second + ":" + DateTime.Now.Millisecond + " = " + ligne);                        
                    previousligne = ligne;
                    compteur++;
                    if (compteur % 10 == 0)
                    {
                        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Users\Public\WriteLines.txt", "---------" + compteur);
                        Console.WriteLine("---------" + compteur);
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

If you know Final Fantasy X, I'm trying to automate the process of avoiding the lightning bolts : [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qkRJZn3q-FA)

I could just cheat to get the ingame result (or do it the legit way) and it would have already been done, but if I can learn a bit more of C# instead it would be better.

Answer (score 1):

The console window (i.e. your running process) is the active window which `SendKeys` is sending data to. Since the console doesn't have a message loop, there is nowhere for the message to be received at, and it's lost. You would need to activate the target window with something like [`SetActiveWindow()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646311%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

See also [How do I send key strokes to a window without having to activate it using Windows API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220820/how-do-i-send-key-strokes-to-a-window-without-having-to-activate-it-using-window)