# Is there any way to send key(s) to other application without focus?

Tags: c#, sendkeys

I have spent 3 days with this topic. All results that I found uses "SetForeground" and then, SendMessage or some APIs(keybd_event, kennedy(opensource) or etc). Of course, SendKeys does not send key(s) to specified process, I want to send key(s) to specified process that I know the PID or HWND.

I have no ideas of it, is it possible?
If not, I'd rather implement with SetForeground that I unintended.

Any ideas?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220820/how-do-i-send-key-strokes-to-a-window-without-having-to-activate-it-using-window) is good for you. If you can work with WinAPI `SetForeground` function, it is not too difficult to convert SendMessage to C#

Comment: @Sakura Definitely related ask and question. But adopted answer said it should need focus. I'll try the second answer that is not adopted. Thank you.

Comment: This is the key: `you need to find its HWND handle first, and then post appropriately-formatted WM_KEYUP/DOWN and WM_CHAR messages directly to it`. It work, assume you know how to `format WM_KEYUP/DOWN and WM_CHAR message`. Find some p/invoke document about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the solution.

I didn't know about tab concept. The key point was tab handle, the real handle for key processing. If I use main window handle, it can process **WM_CLOSE** **WM_SETTEXT** (also **SetWindowText(string)**) but not **WM_KEYDOWN**. I imagined the sequence.

1. keyboard stroke
2. key event to the handle (main window handle)
3. handle gives to received event WM_KEYDOWN / WM_CHAR / WM_KEYUP with VK_*

So I must find the tab handle first.

```
int getTabHandle() {
    int hwnd = 0;
    hwnd = FindWindowEx(hwnd , 0, "iexplore.exe", null);
    hwnd = FindWindowEx(hwnd , 0, "IEFrame", null);
    hwnd = FindWindowEx(hwnd , 0, "Frame Tab", null);
    hwnd = FindWindowEx(hwnd , 0, "TabWindowClass", null);
    hwnd = FindWindowEx(hwnd , 0, "Shell DocObject View", null);
    hwnd = FindWindowEx(hwnd , 0, "Internet Explorer_Server", null);
    return hwnd;
}
```

With this hwnd, I could send key without focus. Thanks.