# vbs SendKeys only to specific window

Tags: vbscript

I have this VBScript

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "KEYS TO SEND"
```

This code will send Keys Strokes to Ative Top window

How can I send the keystrokes only to specific window?

Comment: Use `WshShell.AppActivate "YOUR DESIRED WINDOW"`

Comment: I need to do this to cmd, how can I do?

Comment: Use above statement in your script!

Comment: this does not work, thank you for your time anyways

Comment: Does not work?? What is your target window? Can't it be said publicly?

Comment: My target window is cmd, I need to put some automatic codes but all in background. without interact with another windows, vbscript just interact with cmd

Answer (score 5):

The intended way in WSH is to first activate the window with [`WshShell.AppActivate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wzcddbek(v=vs.84).aspx) as others noted.

As per [How do I send key strokes to a window without having to activate it using Windows API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220820/how-do-i-send-key-strokes-to-a-window-without-having-to-activate-it-using-window) , **in WinAPI, you cannot reliably send keystrokes to anything but the active window.**

If you intend to try anyway (don't complain <s>if</s> when things go wrong), as per the linked question, you need to send a series of messages to the window with `SendMessage`.

There's no built-in way in WSH to call WinAPI. So, either use another language whose standard library provides access to WinAPI and/or wrappers over them, or a 3rd-party COM object like [DynamicWrapperX](http://www.script-coding.com/dynwrapx_eng.html).

---

As a side note, you may wish to consider a dedicated UI automation language like AutoIt or Autohotkey. The former can be called via a COM interface if you still need to use WSH for some reason.