# Is there a way to send strings as keystrokes like autohotkey?

Tags: linux, go, autohotkey, go-packages

I moved from Windows to Linux and want to use AutoHotKey. I've tried using autokey but I really didn't like it. Is it possible to use golang to simply send strings as keystrokes to other programs?

Comment: Related: https://github.com/micmonay/keybd_event https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220820  I don't know of any ready made library for this functionality, but you can probably use translate a string into the appropriate keystrokes in keybd_event.  Keep in mind that not every string character translates to a valid key combination

Comment: You could use  `bash -c "xsel -ib <<< 'my string'"` to copy "my string"` to the clipboard, and then `ctrl+v`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [github.com/micmonay/keybd_event](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/micmonay/keybd_event) package provides an API for simulating keystrokes cross-platform, I.e on Linux, MacOS and Windows.

The API does not however provide a way of mapping strings to a sequence of keypresses. That you will have to implement yourself or alternatively, if you want us to help, describe how you would like the strings to be mapped to keypresses.